# how to specify width and height of a drawable item

Tags: android, layout

Hi is there anyway of providing width and height of a drawable defined in drawable.xml in drawable folder.

Example:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

I wanted to specify width and height maybe somehow using "**scale**" tag inside it which i tried but didnt worked. This is my code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ratingstar">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="20" android:scaleHeight="20" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ratingstar" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: The only attributes I can see that might work is to use something like this 
<scale
    android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_resource"
    android:scaleHeight="percentage"
    android:scaleWidth="percentage" />

Answer (score 6):

layer-list will help: here change values according to your requirement

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/slider_knob" />
```

Comment: You can't specify width and height inside item tag, I don't see that mentioned in documentation.

Comment: @user606669 You can but it's only supported after API 23

Comment: How can I use it before api 23?

Comment: This is not working!

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute `width` and `height` in API level 23 and higher:

```
<item
    android:width="18dp" android:height="18dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ratingstar"/>
```

For lower API levels, I do not know a way of specifying `width` and `height` directly. The best practice is scaling drawables as far as I know.

Comment: This is not working!

Answer (score 0):

With selector and drawable you can do it like this for example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" >
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_first_drawable"  
               android:height="25dp" android:width="25dp"/>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" >
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_second_drawable"  
               android:height="25dp" android:width="25dp"/>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: This is not working!

Answer (score -17):

You can specify inside the `<item>` tag the `width` and `height` of the `drawable`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:width="100dp"
       android:height="20dp"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:width="100dp"
       android:height="20dp"
       android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
```

Comment: The above does not actually work. `StateListDrawable` (selector) does not actually have a width and height property.

Comment: @Sent1nel Definitely. One can use `width` and `height` with (XML) `ShapeDrawable` if that's what's behind the `item`s, though.

Comment: Even when I have a shape as the root element of the drawable this doesn't seem to work. I don't suppose you have a working example?

Comment: Dude, this answer is not actually wrong. The property `android:width` and `android:height` are exists but only in API level 23 and higher.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to delete the answer :)

Comment: This is not working!