# How to resize bitmap

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to implement to spinner a style , but triangle icon goes too big , how is possible to control its dimension ???

style.xml

```
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

gradient_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />

                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_arrow"
                android:gravity="bottom|right"
                />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

how looks gradient spinner at the moment
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhYW9.jpg

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7530960/4706693    and look at the ` <size android:width="30" android:height="40"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resize bitmap using java code.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
int height = (bitmap.getHeight() * 512 / bitmap.getWidth());
Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512,height, true);
image.setImageBitmap(scale);
```

Comment: I use this in application to resize bitmap.

Comment: here i dont declare bitmap in class , just use it in xml

Comment: or  android:scaleType="fitXY"